# Fiddler Core C# - converting forms application to a C# command prompt project

Tags: c#, fiddlercore

I followed a tutorial on the web on how to build a fiddlercore C# application which grabs the post URLs and output them to listbox1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void UpdateUI();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += new Fiddler.SessionStateHandler(FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete);
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(0, Fiddler.FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
    }

    void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUI(() =>
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(oSession.url);
            }));

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

How can I Covert this application into a command project that just outputs in the command window project?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the FiddlerCore folder that the installer creates, there's a project/folder titled **Demo**. It is a command-line application that is exactly what you are asking for.